# What image formats are supported by Gdk-Pixbuf (Gtk-Image?) by Default?

Tags: c, image, image-processing, gtk, gdkpixbuf

I know that Gdk-Pixbuf supports png and jpg, but I cannot find an *exact list* of all the completely (or partially) supported image formats anywhere on the internet. It is necessary for my current project, since I need to check the extension of every file in a directory and determine whether it is supported or not by gdk-pixbuf. Any help?

Comment: GdkPixbuf is an standard for keeping raw image data, so GdkPixbufLoaders are the ones who support loading jpg/png into GdkPixbuf, so you should read about GdkPixbuf loaders, and check which one support your environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling [`gdk_pixbuf_get_formats()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-Module-Interface.html#gdk-pixbuf-get-formats) in your application will tell you which formats your copy of GDKPixbuf can load.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is 5+ years old but I had trouble finding this for PyGI / PyGObject (3.22.0).

```
import gi.repository.GdkPixbuf as pixbuf
```

Then we can get all the formats using:

```
for f in pixbuf.Pixbuf.get_formats():
    print f.get_name()
```

On my system (might be different on yours if you installed other loaders), I get:

- ani
- bmp
- GdkPixdata
- gif
- icns
- ico
- jpeg
- png
- pnm
- qtif
- svg
- tga
- tiff
- wmf
- xbm
- xpm

Comment: List supported formats along with their MIME types: `python3 -c "import gi.repository.GdkPixbuf as pixbuf;from pprint import pprint;pprint([(f.get_name(), f.get_mime_types()) for f in pixbuf.Pixbuf.get_formats()])"`

Answer (score 1):

This should be available by querying [gdk-pixbuf-loaders](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders.html).
Here is more information on [pixbuf modules](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-Module-Interface.html#gdk-pixbuf-Module-Interface.description) and [supported formats](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-Module-Interface.html#gdk-pixbuf-get-formats).

Comment: Please have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711638/how-to-disconnect-an-accelerator-or-key-press-event-in-a-gtk-widget