# How to "disconnect" an accelerator , key-press-event or mouse-press-event in a GTK+ Widget?

Tags: c++, c, custom-controls, gtk

Say I have a custom GTK+ widget obtained from a third party library. It has an accelerator, e.g it hides itself when I press 'h' or click it, and shows itself when I press 'h' again or double-click it. I want disable this *particular* functionality of the GTK+ widget. How can I do this without changing the source code of the Library and rebuilding it?

Note: You can also give your solution in c++ , in fact it would be better that way because I am using C++ for my project.

Comment: I'm using python. There is a "accelerator-group" that has all the short-cuts, where you can remove one : http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkaccelgroup.html#method-gtkaccelgroup--disconnect-key

Comment: The best way to know how you need to block the functionality of the widget is by reading the widget code. And then go through the Gtk API to block it. I think it depends on how the widget implemented the thing itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing now, but how about gtk_widget_can_activate_accel () ?

http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-can-activate-accel