# The function "GdkPixbuf.from_file" doesn't work well

Tags: image, ocaml, gdk, gdkpixbuf

I use Lablgtk and all functions except the function "GdkPixbuf.from_file" work well.
I can compile the code including the function "GdkPixbuf.from_file", but I can't execute it.
When I type the command "./programname" to execute it,  I get an error:

```
Fatal error: exception GdkPixbuf.GdkPixbufError(3, "Couldn't recognize the image file  
format for file 'filename.jpg'")
```

The code which doesn't include the function "GdkPixbuf.from_file" can be executed.
What should I do to make the function "GdkPixbuf.from_file" work well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that your `GdkPixbuf` doesn't support `jpg` files. You can either convert your image file to another format, like:

```
convert filename.jpg filename.png
```

Or you can try to install supporting modules. Some more information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704670/what-image-formats-are-supported-by-gdk-pixbuf-gtk-image-by-default)

Comment: I convert filename.jpg filename.png, but I get error.

Comment: I read the linked page in "Some more information can be found here".

Comment: Oh, my comment is on the way. Sorry.

Comment: First, thank you for your comment, ivg. In the linked page, I can't get the information to solve the error. I thought the command "gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache" solves the problem and tried, but it could't solve the problem. Do you have any ideas?